# Why is the norm convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Why is the norm a convex function?

Comment: The norm of *what*????

Comment: @coffeemath: What do you mean? The norm is a function. Functions can be convex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By triangle inequality 
\begin{align}
\left\|ax + \left(1-a\right)y \right\|\le \left\|ax \right\| + \left\|\left(1-a\right)y \right\|= a\left\|x \right\| + \left(1-a\right)\left\|y\right\|
\end{align}